# spark javaRDD output to database

Tags: java, apache-spark, sqoop

Please help me understand what would be the best way to save output of `spark javaRDD` into database?

Should I write spark java code to save `RDD` into database? What would be drawback of this approach ?

Or I should use `sqoop` to save output files into database?

Is there any other way to to this?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your response  but i think if we use foreachpartitioner  it's difficult to deal with failure,  
what if network broken in half of the process?  should we drop all data in database and restart from beginning?  if the process is "Appending" data to database, then things becomes even complex . so i think instead of using forEachParrtition  we can use dataframe  to save  data ? please let me know is there any drawback of this approach

Comment: solved it using dataframe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

used dataframe and saved data into sql server

```
SQLContext sqlcontext=new SQLContext(context);
DataFrame outDataFrame=sqlcontext.createDataFrame(finalOutPutRDD, WebHttpOutPutVO.class);
Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
prop.setProperty("database", "Web_Session");
prop.setProperty("user", "user");
prop.setProperty("password", "pwd@123");
prop.setProperty("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
outDataFrame.write().mode(org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Append).jdbc("jdbc:sqlserver://<Host>:1433", "test_table", prop);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can use for writing your results back to the database.

1. Use something like DBOutputFormat and configure that
2. Use foreachPartition on the RDD you want to save and pass in a function which creates a connection to MySQL and writes the result back.